# my %s is not working . whenever i use it is shows 'None' [Python 3.6]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
data = {"act":"login","class":"profile","prftcf":"%s"%(code1),"p":"%s"%(password1),"u":"%s"%(username1),"ver":"0.9.1"}
```

Where `password1` and `username1` with `%s` are working fine and `password1` and `username1` are `raw_input` .

My variable `code1` is a string:

```
code1 = "OTcwMzAzY2NjY2NjY2NjY6eZwkOnclZLYgFCeIDITYbkoKNqeZFIOLYr97sRo5GNGwqpSh7RqlUn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\nYeVmugGm86o8p+N019vB2T0Gc3qKhjAY3FyvCMwizzOLi1Ev9J8=\n+00+00"
```

and my output is coming out like this :

```
    {"act":"login","class":"profile","prftcf":"None","p":"asdasd","u":"asdasd","ver":"0.9.1"}
```

It isn't showing `code1` its showing `None`

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Probably somewhere else in your code you re-assigned `code1` to something that returned `None`

Comment: Nope i didn't , even i tried printing code1 before assigning it to that string to keep a check

Comment: Create a simple combined code example showing the issue.

Comment: Either paste more of your code or create a minimal complete verifiable example. %s shouldn’t be your problem @quora

Comment: The behavior you are describing is not reproducible. Add an example that is.

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: i got it fixed hehe . Yeah it was assigned somewhere else  . Thanks bro : )

Answer (score 0):

code1 value is same here as you and username1 and password1 is different, all values are strings:-

```
code1="OTcwMzAzY2NjY2NjY2NjY6eZwkOnclZLYgFCeIDITYbkoKNqeZFIOLYr97sRo5GNGwqpSh7RqlUn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\nYeVmugGm86o8p+N019vB2T0Gc3qKhjAY3FyvCMwizzOLi1Ev9J8=\n+00+00"
password1="hello"
username1="akki"
data = {"act":"login","class":"profile","prftcf":"%s"%(code1),"p":"%s"%(password1),"u":"%s"%(username1),"ver":"0.9.1"}
print (data)
```

Result:

```
{'class': 'profile', 'act': 'login', 'ver': '0.9.1', 'p': 'hello', 'prftcf': 'OTcwMzAzY2NjY2NjY2NjY6eZwkOnclZLYgFCeIDITYbkoKNqeZFIOLYr97sRo5GNGwqpSh7RqlUn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\nYeVmugGm86o8p+N019vB2T0Gc3qKhjAY3FyvCMwizzOLi1Ev9J8=\n+00+00', 'u': 'akki'}
```

You have not posted the full code above, so may be somewhere in you program the value of code1 becomes `null` or can say `None`. Or paste the full code once and i will try to tell the proper reason of the error coming.